# Change Tab Bar Programmatically

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, tabs

I'm trying to change the tab view when a button is clicked. I have this code:

```
- (IBAction)startScratch:(id)sender {
     _mainTabBar.tabBarController.selectedIndex = 1;
        //Error: ^ Property tabBarController not found on type "NSTabView*"
}
```

The .h file has these lines of code:

```
@property (weak) IBOutlet NSTabView *mainTabBar;
- (IBAction)startScratch:(id)sender;
```

I'm assuming I should replace _mainTabBar with something, but if so, what?

Comment: The error is obvious, the compiler tells you what it is. `NSTabView` has no priperty called `tabBarController`. What are you trying to do?

Comment: I said what I was trying to do, change the tab view when a button was clicked. I found the base idea from [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5413538/switching-to-a-tabbar-tab-view-programmatically?rq=1). Again, I'm terrible at Objective-C, so I'm not sure what I'm doing.

Comment: Huh? That's for iOS... Instead of making assumptions, you should read the documentation...

Answer (score 13, accepted):

As @H2CO3 mentioned, there is no `tabBarController` property in `NSTabView`. If you read [the documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/nstabview_Class/Reference/Reference.html), you’ll notice that `NSTabView` provides a few selection methods, including [`-selectTabViewItemAtIndex:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/nstabview_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSTabView/selectTabViewItemAtIndex%3a), which you can use like so:

```
- (IBAction)startScratch:(id)sender {
    [_mainTabBar selectTabViewItemAtIndex:1];
}
```

Note that the first tab is at index 0.

Comment: Thank you, I've been struggling with this for a while.