# tabBarController unLoad itself after call modalView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitabbarcontroller, modal-view

I have tabBarController with 6 views. As default tabBarController load first view, I need to load view #6 at my application start, so in my tabBarController I add to `viewWillAppear` `[self.tabBarController setSelectedIndex:6];`, ok. In my view #3 a have 2 modal views witch I create in storyboard. When I tap a button I load my modal view, and when a close it `[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES]`; (I was in view #3) I see view #6, but I need to come back to view #3, so if I understand right when I call my modalView it unload my tabBarController and when I close it load tabBarController again with view #6, but i need to see my view #6 where i call my modalView, how can I fix it?

P.S. I hope you understand my English

Comment: Your understanding is incorrect -- the tab bar controller is not unloaded when you present a modal controller.

Comment: @rdelmar incorrect, but viewWillAppear works after modalView closes. How to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I change order of items in my tabBarController in storyboard, change numbers of views in code and everything works. Thanks to all.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like You added `[self.tabBarController setSelectedIndex:6];` to `viewWillAppear` instead of `viewDidLoad`. There is no viewWillLoad there.

Comment: if i put it in viewDidLoad my app load first page instead of six

Answer (score 0):

Do something like this in the viewDidAppear method of your tab bar controller, so it only sets the selectedIndex when the app starts up:

```
-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
    static BOOL isFirst = YES;
    if (isFirst) {
        [self setSelectedIndex:6];
        isFirst = NO;
    }
}
```

Comment: @RomanSimenok, what do you mean by your comment? Are you getting an error message? If, so you need to post the code you tried.

Comment: yes, error, but viewDidAppear is wrong way, for example even if i put there [self.tabBarController setSelectedIndex:6]; it will always send me to the 6 page, so only viewWillLoad works here, i try to make come "if" there, but i get only errors.

Comment: @RomanSimenok, it shouldn't always send you to 6, only the first time the view appears. I've tested my code and it works fine for me.  As I said above, you should edit your question to show the code you're using now.