# Delegate returns nil

Tags: ios, objective-c, delegates, storyboard, modalviewcontroller

I have storyboard with two views, one is main second is modal. So when i tap button in first view i call my modal view(no code, all in storyboard) and i need to close my modal view using a delegate. So in my first view i write

```
First.h

#import "Modal.h"

@interface SkyViewController: UIViewController <ModalDelegate>

First.m

in viewDidLoad
ModalView *modal = [[Modal alloc] init];
modal.delegate = self;

-(void)exit
{
   [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

**Modal View**

```
Modal.h

@protocol ModalDelegate;

@interface ModalView : UIViewController

....

@property (assign) id<ModalDelegate> delegate;

.....

@protocol ModalDelegate

-(void)exit;

@end
```

in main

```
Modal.m

....
@syntesize delegate;

...

-(void)buttonPressed
{
   [delegate exit];
}
```

what am i doing wrong? i see in google that it can bee some problem in owners in storyboard... I don't know :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is

```
  ModalView *modal = [[Modal alloc] init].
```

This creates a new instance of your modal view, not the one you get on screen with a button click. You should implement prepareForSegue, and set your delegate there. ModalView will be the segue.destinationViewController.

```
-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {

    ModalView *modal = segue.destinationViewController;
    modal.delegate = self;
}
```

This code goes in your first controller.

Comment: Would you be so kind to write some example code, i'm new in objective C :)

Comment: Mother of Good! It works! Thank you very much!!! Can't vote up, low reputation :(

now i'll try to solve my previous question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19742416/tabbarcontroller-unload-itself-after-call-modalview , you were there :)

Answer (score 3):

You should make the delegate weak instead of 'assign'.

Comment: doesn't work for me :(
[delegate exit]; - here my delegate nil :(

Comment: Is the ModalViewController a property or just a variable that lives for the life of viewDidLoad as suggested?

Your code has been presented in a really odd way. Perhaps if I had the actual code to look at I could help.