# Change Tab in TabBar at runtime

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitabbarcontroller

I'm trying to change the tab in my `Tabbar` dynamically.

I've added a class for `UITabBarController`.

In the first Tab controller I've placed a button and on click i want to switch to the third tab at runtime.

**I'm an absolute beginner so I'm not sure how this works**

On click of the button I'm using

```
[self.tabBarController selectedIndex:2]
```

But i'm getting an error that says:

> No visible interface declares the selector 'selectedIndex'

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Switching to a TabBar tab view programmatically?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5413538/switching-to-a-tabbar-tab-view-programmatically)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is `setSelectedIndex`. You are mixing two syntax.

```
[self.tabBarController setSelectedIndex:2];
```

**Or either you can set it like this**

```
self.tabBarController.selectedIndex = 2;
```

Comment: Worked perfectly fine. Thanks mate

Comment: @jamian Welcome mate :)